# Was there any official affirmation from the US government that they would win the Vietnam War?

Tags: united-states, vietnam-war

One thing that the Vietnam War showed is that there are no set parameters that can foretell the outcome of a war, such as the article in [The Computer That Predicted the U.S. Would Win the Vietnam War
A cautionary tale about the dangers of big data](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2017/10/the-computer-that-predicted-the-us-would-win-the-vietnam-war/542046/)  explain with interesting facts on big data history.

However, one piece of information that I could not directly find in my research is if there was any official or media interview declaration where one or some personalities made an affirmation on the assuredness of US victory in the Vietnam War.

Is there any citation, picture, transcription or online archive that contains any such citations, if they exist?

Comment: One does not commit the lives of the military to a conflict you don't intend to win.  The question is borderline offensive.

Comment: How would you define the "USA has won the war"? In some wars, this is easy. For example in the WWII, Germany and Japan have been conquered. But in the VIetnam war, it was very difficult to define what victory meant.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, I'm sorry but by the point of view of Historians, this is not a thousand light years from offensive. Anyone intrested in History has to be ready to question any decision or fact that happened in the past, not for judging, but for searching fragments of truth. Also, its not hard to find situations where other factors weighted more in the decision of a war than human life, such as ideology and economic intrest. This does not sociologically disqualify an intention, but rather explains better its true nature.

Comment: @BernardMassé, this is an intresting statement. Sure it is a very hard to qualify term, for even I learned in high school that US was the real victor in the war. But as a matter of a consensus of "who forfeit, loses" (with a pardon to all the polemics raised by such simple phrasing), this is my definition of "winning the war". Trailing into details onto this path may put lose the intention of the question, which is directed to show that not always military superiority and assuredness of victory can actually bring a victory - as the phrase says, theres more to life than...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any number of statements can be interpreted as such. Take for instance President Lyndon Johnson's [speech at the John Hopkins University](http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/?pid=26877) in 1965, shortly after regular combat troops began to be deployed to Vietnam. He bluntly asserted that:

> And we do this to convince the leaders of North Vietnam, and all who seek to share their conquest, of a very simple fact: **We will not be defeated.**

Moreover, this was not even the only such statement in that speech. Nearer the end, he reiterated that:

> Well, we will choose life. In so doing **we will prevail** over the enemies within man, and over the natural enemies of all mankind.

Comment: Minor quibble:  the second remark does not specifically mention Vietnam.  The first says we will not lose, not that we will win.